# IE11's combobox weird behavior (bug) - wrong pageX and pageY values for selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, combobox, internet-explorer-11

```
$(window).on('click', function(event) {
        if (event.pageY < 10 && event.pageY < 10) {
            alert('WTF?');
        }
});
```

What is special with this code? Nothing.
However when I select item inside Combobox and then click it once more, pageX and pageY coordinates have values relative to the left upper corner of the selection instead of the whole document.

Here is the [captured video](http://screencast.com/t/TyQT5P6w) with bug(?) reproduction.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested comboboxes specifically, but both Chrome and IE exhibit odd behavior for `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` within open `select` elements.

A possible solution is to attach a a `mousemove` event, and save its `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` coordinates for use within the `click` event.

Below is a snippet, which displays the event coordinates for `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `click`, and `mousemove`.  For the `select` element, you'll notice inconsistencies between browsers.  Chrome doesn't even register a `mousemove` when the `select` box is open.

```js
$(window).on('mousedown mouseup click mousemove', function(event) {
  $('#'+event.type).html('<td>'+event.type+
                         '<td>'+event.target+
                         '<td>'+event.pageX+
                         '<td>'+event.pageY
                        )
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 1em;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  font: 12px arial;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

th {
  background: #def;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button>Test</button>
  <select>
    <option>Option 1
    <option>Option 2
    <option>Option 3
  </select>
</div>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr><th>event.type<th>event.target<th>event.pageX<th>event.pageY
  <tr id="click">
  <tr id="mouseup">
  <tr id="mousedown">
  <tr id="mousemove">
</table>
```